# Casting dates without time components using CType gives an inconsistant result

Tags: vb.net

Some code I am working on dumps information from a sql query into a csv file by casting every element returned into a string with:

```
CType(item, String)
```

When item is a Date object that has a zero time component, some computers return a string with " 00:00:00" on the end and some return a string with no time component. I'm guessing that it has something to do with localization, but I can't find how CType handles localization and the computers are *supposed* to be all configured with the default UK localization.

Does anyone know the specific reason this is happening?

Comment: That's not a cast.  For something be cast as type `String`, it has to already be a `String`.  That basically means that you have a variable of type `Object` that refers to a `String` instance.  If you have a `Date` value and you want a `String` then you're doing a conversion, not a cast.  Think of the expression "to cast something in a different light".  That literally means to make the same thing look different.  That's how casting works in programming.  The object doesn't change but the way you refer to it does.  If the type of the object changes, that's a conversion.

Comment: Don't use `CType` at all.  Call the `ToString` method of the `Date` and you can then provide a format specifier, which means that you will always get that format regardless of who runs the code and where they run it.